# Saving webpage as pdf with selenium and chromedriver with not default name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Could anyone tell me if there is any option to save pdf file with not default name? In my code everything works fine, the only thing i would like to change is a name of file. Maybe i should add something in setting or prefs? I would like the name to be the same what user input at the begining of the script. Thats the part of my code. Thanks for help in advance.

```
isin = input('Please provide ISIN: ')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
settings = {
       "recentDestinations": [{
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": "",
        }],
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2
    }
prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings),
         'savefile.default_directory': 'PATH'}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
```

Comment: When creating a code block you need to indent _or_ fence it, but not both. And if you're fencing, you need to use backticks (`\``), not single quotes (`'`).

Comment: There isn't any for filename only directory to save in. Use shututil to rename the file after download.